# Why do the Regex is not working properly?

Tags: java, regex

I have some `String` like

`s3://my-source-bucket/molomics/molecules35455720556210282.csv` or, 
`s3://my-source-bucket/molecules10282.csv`
`s3://my-source-bucket/molename`

Criterias:

```
1. the portion of `s3://` is fixed
2. the bucket name will be consists of letters, numbers and dash(-) and dots(.), say, 
my-source-bucket and will be followed by /
3. Number 2 will repeat one or more time
4. In the end there will be no /
```

I would like to match them using the regex. I have this small program that I use to get the matches provided below,

```
public static void findMatchUsingRegex(String input) {

    String REGEX = "(w+://)([0-9A-Za-z-]+/)([0-9A-Za-z-/]+)([0-9A-Za-z-.]+)?";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);   // get a matcher object
    while(m.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Match number "+count);
        System.out.println("start(): "+m.start());
        System.out.println("end(): "+m.end());
    }
}
```

In the online editor, I find the matches.However, these doesn't return anything as expected in the actual run of the program. How to change the regex to work it properly and may be to work better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Some points in order

1. Criterion #1 states that `s3://` is fixed, so you can use that explicitly.
2. You need to escape special regex characters like `.`, `-`, and `/`. Because you're writing the regex as a Java string, you'll need to use two backslashes: `\\.` to match the literal `.`.
3. It looks like you can simplify your pattern quite a bit.
4. I don't know exactly what `findMatchUsingRegex` is supposed to do, but make sure you want to use `Pattern.find` over `Pattern.match`.

#### A solution

`s3:\/(\/[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+)+`

Note how the `\/` comes first, so the string must end with a  number, letter, `.`, or `-`. In Java, you'll need to write this as:

`s3:\\/(\\/[0-9A-Za-z\\-\\.]+)+`

(Technically, you don't need to escape `-` and `.` here. But that's probably good practice because they're special characters.)